# Existential quantifier axioms in Halmos' system, equivalence proof needed

Tags: logic

I have to refer to page 21 of the book cited in the link below. There is a list of axioms Q1-Q5, and an assertion that they are equivalent to a shorter set, namely Q1, Q2 and Q6. I am trying to derive Q6 from Q1-Q5 {I can recall successfully doing something similar to this, if not identical, about 50 years ago when studying the subject}. The stumbling block at present:

I can easily show that :

> $\exists(p \land \exists q) \le \exists p \land \exists q$

by noting that :

> for any $p,q, \quad p \le q \Rightarrow \exists p \le \exists q$,

hence :

> for any $p,q, \quad \exists (p \land q) \le \exists p \land \exists q$,

and so :

> $\exists (p \land \exists q) \le \exists p \land \exists (\exists q) = \exists p \land \exists q$.

But the other inequality:

> $\exists p \land \exists q \le \exists (p \land \exists q)$

has me stuck, despite using Q2-Q5 to expand $\land$-expressions using unions and negations. I'm assuming the axioms are correctly stated - Halmos himself seemed to think the proofs were simple enough to be omitted. Can anyone help or provide a hint?

For the reference, see : Paul Halmos, [Algebraic logic](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=GG3IqlA34E0C&pg=PA21), see page 21.

Comment: Google for StackExchange LaTeX guide. Your question is incredibly hard to read.

Comment: This is an old question, but I just stumbled upon the same problem while reading the very same book. This is not that straightforward, it is actually proven later in the book in some more detail, more specifically on pages 38 through 45.

Answer (score 0):

We may at least verify it.

If we consider : $\exists (p \land \exists q)$, we have that :

*(i)* when $\exists q = 1$, then $\exists (p \land \exists q) = \exists p$;

*(ii)* when $\exists q = 0$, then $\exists (p \land \exists q) = \exists 0 = 0$, by axiom **(Q1)**.

The same clearly apply to $\exists p \land \exists q$, and thus :

> $\exists (p \land \exists q) = \exists p \land \exists q$.

---

For a "more formal" proof :

1) $p \land \exists q \le p \le \exists p$, by axiom **(Q2)**.

$\exists$ is *monotone*, i.e. : if $p \le q$, then $\exists p \le \exists q$.

Thus, from above it follows that : $\exists (p \land \exists q) \le \exists \exists p = \exists p$, by axiom **(Q4)**.

Also : $p \land \exists q \le \exists q$, and again : $\exists (p \land \exists q) \le \exists q$.

Thus : $\exists (p \land \exists q) \le \exists p, \exists q$, and so :

> $\exists (p \land \exists q) \le \exists p \land \exists q$.

2) $p= (p \land \exists q) \lor (p \land (\exists q)') \le (p \land \exists q) \lor (\exists q)'$, and thus :

$\exists p \le \exists [(p \land \exists q) \lor (\exists q)']= \exists (p \land \exists q) \lor \exists (\exists q)' = \exists (p \land \exists q) \lor (\exists q)'$, by axioms **(Q3)** and **(Q5)**.

Now we form the infimum of both sides of this relation with $\exists q$ :

> $\exists p \land \exists q \le \exists (p \land \exists q) \land \exists q \le \exists (p \land \exists q)$.

From 1) and 2) we have that :

> > $\exists (p \land \exists q) = \exists p \land \exists q$.

Comment: In general we're working with a Boolean algebra A of propositional functions, with "E" (don't know how to get the backwards symbol) as a mapping A=>A, so we need more ....

Comment: Sorry - I think you're correct - I was trying to prove things at the wrong level of abstraction regarding the values of the existential operator.